# How to detect user's Regional Settings with jQuery in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, settings, regional-settings

I want to detect with JavaScript or jQuery what are the Regional Settings of the current user in NewForm.

This is want I want to get from user:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one:

```
var url = ctx.HttpRoot+"/_layouts/regionalsetng.aspx?Type=User";
$.get(url,function(data){
    $(data).find("select[name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl00$ctl00$DdlwebLCID]").find(":selected").each(function(){
        var lcid  = $(this).attr("value");
        var cultureInfo  = $(this).text();
    });
});
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6a33dd2b-c138-4c86-a002-42d08d941362/retrieve-regional-settings-by-javascript?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: can somebody post the full implementation? I am calling this method in my custom js and sp.js is giving runtime error.