# Getting the Timezone in Regional setting using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, server

I want to get the timezone in SharePoint, which is set in the regional settings. To be specific it is set as Japan Time. I am using javascript to fetch the time, but unfortunately I can't.

I tried this:

```
var value = SP.RegionalSettings.get_timeZones ()
```

which can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245450.aspx)

and this

```
var object = new SP.TimeZone()
```

which can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246865.aspx)

Is there something that I miss before using this? Or is there something I need to configure before I can use this in my codes.

Answer (score 5):

With REST:

`_api/Web/RegionalSettings/TimeZone`

With JSOM:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var timeZone = ctx.get_web().get_regionalSettings();
ctx.load(timeZone);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
  console.log(timeZone);
});
```

2010:
It does not seem easy to do this in 2010. [Here](http://sympmarc.com/tag/timezone/) is a solution by Marc, which is based of [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/112561/627) by Waqas Sarwar.
Another options is to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16190864) by lem.mallari which use `Utility.FormatDateTime` to convert a given time to the site timezone. I have converted the last answer from CSOM to JSOM:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var dt = new Date();
var res = SP.Utilities.Utility.formatDateTime(ctx, ctx.get_web(), dt.toISOString(), SP.Utilities.DateTimeFormat.dateTime);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function()  {
  console.log(dt, res.get_value());
});
```

Comment: I have found this same solution, but pardon me though, I am still new to sharepoint and I don't have any clue about REST and JSOM, I'll ask again, is there anything that I need to configure first before putting this in my codes?

I tried to run this on my codes and I guess it does not recognize any of the lines. Just a heads up, I am coding in workflow management at sharepoint which is very annoying because it limits the ability to use javascript syntax.

Comment: If you are writing a workflow, could you not make it [call out to SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558.aspx)?

Comment: Anyway to get this to work with SharePoint 2010? Right now I'm getting the error `Object doesn't support property or method 'get_regionalSettings'`.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Didn't seem like an easy task. I have updated the answer for 2010, at least what I was able to find.

Answer (score 0):

`JSOM` or `JavaScript Object Model` is a coding practice in which we use `JavaScript API` reference for SharePoint 2013. Refer [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193034.aspx) to get an idea

`REST` or `Representational State Transfer` is introduced in SP2013 that is comparable to the existing SharePoint client object models. Refer this [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx) to get more idea and also this [MSDN Magazine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx)

> To get the time zone below JavaScript function can be
>   helpful

```
// Global variable to store time zone object.
var siteTimeZone = '';

// function to get time zone
function getTimeZome(){
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var timeZone = web.get_regionalSettings().get_timeZone();
        context.load(timeZone);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
        function onSucceeded() {
            siteTimeZone = timeZone;
        },
         queryFailure
        );

}

// function to handle failuer 
function queryFailure (sender, args) {
    alert('error');
}

//This is the way you call the function, making sure that sp.js is loaded which contains necessary functions.
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getTimeZome, "sp.js");
```